# Flutter Query 3rd Level Collection in Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a DB that follows a main category, then subcategory, then a 3rd layer called tags.

I can query the subcategories just fine... having a hard time with the 3rd layer.

```
Query collectionReference = Firestore.instance
                            .collection("mainCategories")
                            .document("cKKi9cGKZNbTzgFIkdob")
                            .collection("subCategories")
                            .document("DFUwcMvGce3cidbuJjhW")
                             .collection("tags");
```

DOing the following Queries the Subcategories just fine.

```
Query collectionReference = Firestore.instance
                                .collection("mainCategories")
                                .document("cKKi9cGKZNbTzgFIkdob")
                                .collection("subCategories");
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code is "having a hard time"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I am right... i just had bad code below.